# responsive row of images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to include a row of 7 images on top of a colored div background.
They should display in a row in a normal desktop but break nicely for smaller desktops with the background div following (some text is white otherwise you can't read it).

With all I searched I didn't find a solution.

That's what I have so far:

```
<div class="login_footer container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" >
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/1.png" width="180px"/> 
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/2.png" width="120px" />
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/3.png" width="120px"/>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/4.png" width="120px"/>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/5.png" width="120px"/>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/6.png" width="120px"/>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/7.png" width="120px"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

With this settings the images simply stack - on the desktop.
Am I too naive thinking that putting "img-responsive" would solve everything?
Is setting the width of the images having a negative impact?
The images are unfortunately not all of the same size and I'll have to fiddle there to make them look good.

EDIT: a sketch of how I imagine things:

desktop:

```
|   | img1 || img2 || img3 || img4 || img5 || img6 || img7 |   |
```

smaller display (possible responsive break example):

```
|  | img1 || img2 || img3 |
   | img4 || img5 || img6 |
   | img7 |
|
```

small:

```
|  | img1 |
   | img2 |
   | img3 |
   | img4 |
   | img5 |
   | img6 |
   | img7 |
|
```

Comment: I can see that styling the images with "inline-block" is helping a bit :)

Comment: to clarify, do you want the 7 images to fill the width of the container evenly on desktop?

Comment: maybe best to show a drawing of what you want, and also describe the photo widths exactly...

Comment: @ShawnTaylor yes, I'd like the 7 images to fill the width of the container evenly on desktop, but to start stacking on smaller displays.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure about your question, you can use the flexbox model. Using your HTML, add this CSS

```
.bgrow{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jSNnv5wdpr4/Ug5-RLm3uEI/AAAAAAAALsE/KG0a21yC3HQ/s1600/binary-digital-city-abstract.jpg) no-repeat 50%; background-size:cover; padding:20px;}
.img-row{display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap}
.img-responsive{flex-grow:1; width:auto; max-width:180px; height:auto !important}
```

and you'll have images or divs adjusting to ALL AVAILABLE WIDTH. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uysx0j5m/)

However, if you want to keep the images in the same line, change `flex-wrap` to `nowrap`. Again, not completely sure what do you want to achieve, but with this method you can center horizontally and vertically, re-arrange, reverse, wrap, whatever you can think of. See [Flex Definition at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)  and [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for lots of examples

Answer (score 1):

`.img-responsive` only makes the image max-width:100% to its parent, the parent is the `col-xs-12 col-md-8` in this situation. To make the image row fluid, you can do the following:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zikune/1/edit

**CSS** -- notice how the CSS starts from the smallest to largest. This is to learn from, if you need something more specific try your best and re-post another question.

```
.image-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background:red;
}

.image-list li {
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
}

.image-list li:first-child {
    width: 50%
}

.image-list li:not(:first-child) {
    width: 50%
}

@media (min-width:400px) { 
    .image-list li:first-child {
        width: 25%
    }

    .image-list li:not(:first-child) {
        width: 15.7142857142857%
    }
}

@media (min-width:600px) { 
    .image-list li:first-child {
        width: 20%
    }

    .image-list li:not(:first-child) {
        width: 13.333%
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="login_footer container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <ul class="image-list clearfix">
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/180x100/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x50/000000/FFFFFF&text=image"/></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit confused on what your asking...

But I think your asking how to style your images so that they always fit the screen size?
To do the pictures in a div like so:

```
      <div id="picturebox" >
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/1.png" width="180px"/> 
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/2.png" width="120px" />
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/3.png" width="120px"/>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/4.png" width="120px"/>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/5.png" width="120px"/>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/6.png" width="120px"/>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/7.png" width="120px"/>
      </div>
```

Then in CSS enter:

```
#picturebox{
width: 80%
background-color: grey;
color: white;
}
```

CSS will ensure that the pictures fit in the area

Answer (score 0):

.img-responsive is not a bad class name, but you'd have to set the styles for that class.

Try giving them a percentage width and a min-width.  That way the images will break a line when the screen is smaller than 7 * the min-width, but when there's enough space you can have all 7 in one row.

100/7 = 14.2857143% width for each.  Maybe make it 14% and use the extra for padding between.  Float the images left to be safe when it all ends up equaling 100%.

Comment: .img-responsive is a default class in Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that in the tags.